# Selecting certain character in array

Tags: c, arrays

How can I select a certain character in 2d array and shows it when I print out the output?

For example:

```
int x,y;
char box[4][4];

for(x=0;x<2;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<2;y++)
    {
        box[x][y]='x';
        printf("%c",box[x][y]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

When one of the `x` is selected the output from the screen will be this, a `-` on top and bottom of the character indicate the character is selected.

[image]

Comment: Your code shows a 3x3 array full of `x`:s (fit into the corner of a 5x5 array), your image shows something completely different. This is confusing.

Comment: @unwind I am just giving an example for the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If by selecting a character, you mean printing a hyphen (`-`) above and below the character, then you must compute some formula for the hyphen positions for each element of the array.

Example:

```
Line 1:
Line 2: | x | | x | | x |
Line 3:
Line 4: | x | | x | | x |
Line 5:
Line 6: | x | | x | | x |
Line 7:
```

Now, as you can notice, there is a blank space before each box, and a blank line is inserted between each box for the hyphens.

Each element `[i,j]` is at the position `[Line i*2, Col (j-1)*6+4]`

Let us say you wish to "select" element `[i,j]`, you need to print a hyphen on positions `[Line (i*2)-1, Col (j-1)*6+4]` and `[Line (i*2)+1, Col (j-1)*6+4]`.

To select `[2,3]`, put a hyphen on positions `[3,16]` and `[5,16]`:

```
Line 1:
Line 2: | x | | x | | x |
Line 3:               -
Line 4: | x | | x | | x |
Line 5:               -
Line 6: | x | | x | | x |
Line 7:
```

You can put various values in place of `i` and `j` and see how that works out.

To go to a specific position, you can use a combination of newlines and blank spaces. You can even print 3 hyphens for better clarity!

This is just to give you an idea. For the particular formatting used by your program, you can easily change a value or two in the method above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 9
#define COLS 9

int
main(void) {
    int x, y, row, column;
    char box[ROWS][COLS];

    printf("Enter row of box(1-4): ");
    if (scanf("%d", &row) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter column of box(1-4): ");
    if (scanf("%d", &column) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (x = 0; x < ROWS; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y<COLS; y++) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                box[x][y] = ' ';
            } else {
                box[x][y] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }

    for (x = 1; x < ROWS; x+=2) {
        for (y = 0; y < COLS; y++) {
            if (x == (2*row-1) && y == column - 1) {
                box[x-1][y] = '-';
                box[x+1][y] = '-';
            }
        }
    }


    for (x = 0; x < ROWS; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < COLS; y++) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                printf(" %c ", box[x][y]);
            } else {
                printf("|%c|", box[x][y]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @W.L did this help?